# Calculus problem for increasing function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I need help with this question.

By expressing $$y(x)=\left(\frac{a^x + b^x}2\right)^{1/x} = e^{g(x)} \quad 0<a<b$$

show that $y$ is increasing for $x\ne0$.

I have tried to take ln both sides and got

$$\ln\left[\left(\frac{a^x + b^x}2\right)^{1/x}\right] = g(x)$$

then, when I differentiate $e^g(x)$

$$\frac d {dx} \left(e^{\frac1x\ln\left(\frac{a^x + b^x}2\right)}\right) = -(1/x^3)(((a^x)ln(a)+(b^x)ln(b))/(a^x + b^x) ln((a^x + b^x)/2)$$

It's too complicated...

It was a part of a long question and I was told to relate with the conditions of $$y=\frac{ f(x)}x$$ where $f(0)=0$ and $f"(x) > 0$.

Please help.
Thank you!

Comment: Take logarithms.

Comment: Is it the only way of doing it?

Comment: Take derivative.

Comment: I have tried that. But the thing is I need to show all the working here... Can you explain that more in detail, plz?

Comment: What precisely have you tried?  Can you show the work?

Comment: @heatherlv  I proved that this function decreases. If you want to see my solution show please your attempts.

Comment: **Hint :** $\exp(g(x))$ is decreasing iff $g$ is decreasing. So rather than differentialte $\exp(g)$, differentiate only $g$.

Comment: I've just edited my question. Could you have a look? It is only a part of a long question, but actually, I need help with the whole question... can you plzzzz help with that too...if it's ok with you?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks! That's something I never thought of! Can you also relate that with the fuctions of the form y = f(x)/x, where y=f(x) goes through the origin and is concave up?

Comment: @heatherlv I posted. Ask your question.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Oh, I just read your answer! Is there any way of sending you the photo of the whole question? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logarithmic differentiation makes life easier
$$y=\left(\frac{a^x + b^x}2\right)^{\frac 1x}\implies\log(y)={\frac 1x} \log\left(\frac{a^x + b^x}2\right)={\frac 1x} \log\left(a^x + b^x\right)-\frac {\log(2)} x$$
$$\frac{y'}y=\frac{a^x \log (a)+b^x \log (b)}{x \left(a^x+b^x\right)}-\frac{\log
   \left(a^x+b^x\right)}{x^2}+\frac {\log(2)} {x^2}$$

Simplify what you can and, later, use
$$y'=y\times \frac{y'}y$$ and simplify again.

Answer (score 3):

But it's wrong.

Take $a=2$, $b=3$, $x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$.

We need to prove that $5<\sqrt{13},$ which is wrong.

We can prove that $f(x)=(a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ decreases on $(0,+\infty).$

Indeed, let $\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x=t$.

Thus, $t>1$ and $$f'(x)=\left(e^{\frac{\ln(a^x+b^x)}{x}}\right)'=(a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{\frac{a^x\ln{a}+b^x\ln{b}}{a^x+b^x}\cdot x-\ln(a^x+b^x)}{x^2}=$$
$$=(a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{\frac{a^x\ln{a}+b^x\ln{b}}{a^x+b^x}\cdot x-x\ln a-\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x\right)}{x^2}=$$
$$=(a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{\frac{b^xx\ln{\frac{b}{a}}}{a^x+b^x}-\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x\right)}{x^2}=(a^x+b^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{\frac{t\ln{t}}{1+t}-\ln\left(1+t\right)}{x^2}<0$$

Comment: @heatherlv  Ask your question here.